# How to make a matrix multiplication faster and managable?

Tags: java, matlab, hadoop, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to multiply 2 large matrices in a most efficient way. Particularly, at one hand I have one matrix having dimensions (8.000 X 20.000) and on the other hand, I have the one with dimensions (35.000.000 X 20.000). Both these matrices have the columns with the identical values that is, 20.000 columns are in order and identical for both. Both matrices are too sparse and have boolean (binary) values. By multiplying them, I am trying to grab total commons for each row value.

I applied MATLAB to this end but it was not possible to multiply them due to out of memory issue. So I partitioned the larger matrix and made smaller chunks. Let's say 1.000.000 X 200.
After applying this separation process, I managed to multiply but it took about 5 hours to process even though in matlab this multiplying process is multi-threaded automatically.

I retrieved these matrices in my java script. I was wondering, if there might be faster way for the process. For example, would it make sense to apply Hadoop in java and do the process within java? Or is there any other suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your matrices contain boolean, you can use the type `logical` instead of the default Matlab `double`. That will reduce the memory burden by a factor 8. Also in Matlab there are other ways to find common items than multiplication. Try to update your question with some example code of how you are doing things (with smaller matrix example obviously), indicate the desired output. Then may be someone can propose a better (faster) way of doing the job.

Comment: @Hoki: logical matrices don't support matrix operations (e.g., `*`), only element-wise ones so this would save on storage until the matrices need to be converted back to doubles for math operations. [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/sparse-matrices.html), however, might be a good way to go and could save even more space. I agree, this question is not specific enough.

Comment: @horchler, Thanks for the precision. I forgot about the logical matrices operations restrictions. I was probably already thinking to steer the solution towards logical comparisons rather than actual multiplication.

Comment: Thanks @horchler and hoki. I will prepare a good sample but while preparing it, i would like to give more info. I have already experienced that when i employ sparse matrices, it is good for space issue but it would become amazingly slower since matlab does not support sparse matrix multiplicaion in a multi-threaded way. So i have to convert matrices into doubles again. B y applying this the multiplication is amazingly fast comparing to sparse matrix multiplication.

Comment: For multithreaded sparse matrix multiplications you could try writing a mex file which calls the intel MKL (if you have access to it). I think (not 100% sure) that this operation is multithreaded there.